# d3js v5 + topojson v3 Access to the object's properties in the background

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I'm looking for a tip to access to the object's properties in the background.
Indeed, with a mousehover, I want to reveal the properties of layer *ze.json* (the geographical unit).

However, my proportionnal circles hide this layer.
[image]

I have not really idea of the procedure envisaged because :

- Circle proportional must be on the top
- Opacity doesn't solve the problem

Maybe I should report the information on proportional circles. But how could I transfer this information ? (not only the *population* but also the *ZE name*)

**Proportionnal Circles**

```
let rMax = d3.max(featureCollectionZe.features,(d)=>{return d.properties.pop;});

let propCircle = g.attr("class","prop_circle")
    .selectAll(".prop_circle")
    .data(featureCollectionZe.features)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("transform", (d)=>{return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")";})
    .attr("r",(d)=>{return(Math.sqrt(d.properties.pop/rMax))*30;})
    .attr("fill","#ffa500")
    .attr("fill-opacity",0.8)
    .attr("stroke-width",1)
```

**Mouse event**

```
svgZe
    .on("mouseover",
        (e)=>{return document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=e.properties.nom_ze,
        document.getElementById("pop").innerHTML=e.properties.pop;}
    )
    .on("mouseout",
        (e)=>{return document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="&nbsp",
        document.getElementById("pop").innerHTML="&nbsp";}
    )
```

Here is my code : https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzeHWfChXa348iNBcHWQ

Comment: side notes: zoom can be shortened by `g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);` , what is that purpose of the last `.append("g");` , make the stroke of the `.ze.` more explicit in the style, it is now due to render artefacts that you see the edges

Comment: Thank you for the tip!
Indeed, `.append("g")` has no sense. I had a displacement problem when I click+move the map with the mouse (latency) but seems disappeared now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, that this solves your problem completely, but have you tried to apply `pointer-events: none` CSS property to circles?